# How to get the My Music as the default selected path in a Folder Selection dialog

Tags: c++, special-folders

When opening a folder selection dialog in C++, I'm trying to get the default selected path to be `%USERPROFILE%/My Music`, but I can't figure that out.

```
this->diaActionFolder->SelectedPath = System::Environment::SpecialFolder::MyMusic;
```

The above code results in this error -

> error C2664: 'System::Windows::Forms::FolderBrowserDialog::SelectedPath::set' :
>   cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Environment::SpecialFolder' to 'System::String ^'

I guess that means that `System::Environment::SpecialFolder::MyMusic` is not a string (so presumably it is an object?). In that case, how can I extract the path from it so that I can set it as the default `SelectedPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Environment::GetFolderPath(System::Environment::SpecialFolder::MyMusic)
```

should give the string value.

Comment: Thanks muchly, that does indeed return the string that I was after.